# KendoUI Grid Default Value with Data Annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, data-annotations, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI Grid with ASP.NET MVC Helpers and auto generated columns.

I have `[DefaultValue(60 * 60)]` annotation in my view model but Kendo helpers doesn't seem to respect that.

Can I have default value specified (probably with data annotations) without having to manually describe the columns?

Comment: Make sure binding works in right way and you have turned on Auto Bindig in configuration.

Comment: Everything is binded correctly and Auto Binding is turned on (explicitly)

Comment: You can use default constructor to meet your purpose too. It seems you're working on kendo table, so you can prepare data for inline_read action :)

Comment: Are you setting the `ModelMetadata` in the helper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you defined the columns in the grid manually, you need to set the default value like this despite you defined the default value in the annotation or not

```
 @(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid()
      .DataSource( d=> d.Ajax()
                        .Model(m=>{
                            m.Field(f=>f.YourField).DefaultValue(YourValue);
                 }))
)
```

so for the auto-generated columns you can try the following

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid()
      .Events( e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
)

<script type="text/javascript">
      function onEdit(e) {   
           //check if record is new
           if (e.model.isNew()) {
                // set the value of the model property like this                    
                e.model.set("PropertyName", Value);
                // for setting all fields, you can loop on 
                // the grid columns names and set the field
           }
    }
</script>
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

For default values, I like using the constructor which I believe Kendo should new-up an instance of your model, so this would work.

**View mode**

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Name = "First name";
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

After doing some searching in their docs, it appears that the data annotations or constructor default value are not supported and you must define the default values in the grid definition.  See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-specify-default-property-values-when-a-new-item-is-created for more.

Comment: Updated answer with new info.