# How to avoid the automatic zero value in a Kendo int textbox from Grid Edit screen or inline edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc kendo tools. I have a int property from my c# model side, see below:

```
public class MyModel
{
   [Required]
   public int MyIntField {get;set;
}
```

in the view side I am adding the column using Kendo Grid selector

```
...

.Columns(c => c.Bound(my=>my.MyIntField))

...
```

That field always shows with zero when an edit popup screen is called. How can I avoid that still keeping the automatic required UI validations and without messy changing the DOM directly using javascript?

I'm looking for a kendo selector solution or a c# attribute side solution. But maybe I am asking for too much.

thanks

Comment: This appears to be a repeat of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670471/kendoui-grid-default-value-with-data-annotation and you will want to use datasource model field defaultvalue method

Comment: Make it a nullable int (int?) and validate yourself. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/overview